# Loop through dates in laravel and store in database table with other columns being the same

Tags: laravel

I want to loop through start date and end date in laravel 7. I want to insert the dates in database table with other columns of table remaining the same for each date.
My code for getting all dates between two dates:

```
$leavefrom=$request->leavefrom;
$leaveto=$request->leaveto;     
$period = CarbonPeriod::create($leavefrom, $leaveto);
```

iterating over the period like

```
foreach($period as $date)
```

Can I insert the required data into the table within this foreach loop?

Comment: Yes. You should insert the required data within this foreach loop.

Comment: You need to post how you're inserting the data. and no running insertion query inside a loop is not a good idea, especially when it's depending on external variables like `leavefrom` and `leaveto`. it could be as long as 30 days which is 30 insertion queries.

Comment: Would be useful to see your table structure too!